# to save Listview data in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I have to add 2 buttons with each row in ListView. The buttons are Add and Delete. When user selects one of the buttons then some actions should be taken.
The user selects data from datepicker.I have created save button.When save button gets clicked the data inside listview along with that date must get saved in Sqlite database.How can I do it?
Following is my code.

```
activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/calender"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Enter Date..."
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:textColorHint="#992e28"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calender"
        android:id="@+id/date"/>

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_listview"></ListView>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:text="Save"/>
</LinearLayout>


custom_list.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/delete_btn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="Add" />
</RelativeLayout>

MainActivity.java
package com.example.abc.lvtodb2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lView;
    Button insert;

    EditText date;
    ImageView cal;

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initiate the date picker and a button
        date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        cal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.calender);
        // perform click event on edit text
        cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);//current year
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }


        });


        //generate list
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");
        list.add("item3");
        list.add("item4");
        list.add("item5");

        insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

        //instantiate custom adapter
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(list,MainActivity.this);

        //handle listview and assign adapter
         lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


}


CustomAdapter.java
package com.example.abc.lvtodb2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ABC on 2/14/2017.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return 0;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something
                list.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Item added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your data base class?

Comment: i dont know how to create database class.can anyone give me that code?

Comment: have a look at http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: There are lots of tutorials avilable...plz try them..and than after if  you get any problem than post your concern here....

Comment: @riyakarande which type of code you have tried.

Comment: In most of example data is coming from database in listview.Can anyone give me link in which listview data is sent to database.Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta learn lot of Android things before even you try coding.

1. Learn how to create, insert, update, delete rows in table. SqliteOpenHelper class.
2. Start using Cursor Adaper
3. Try to use ViewHolder pattern for caching your views in getView method
4. You may have to insert/update items based on your click events.

I recommend you to search each topics in google or stackoverflow and see how to do. Nobody is gonna help you to write your own code. You gotta to do.

Best resource : developer.android.com